# Subscription model workflow question: how to handle payments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I feel like I'm missing something with the workflow of subscriptions for an app.

I have an app that allows access to videos with a paid monthly subscription. This is setup through Laravel Cashier with Stripe.

Users should be able to signup, subscribe and make their first payment, and immediately be able to access the paywall content.

My understanding is that the soonest I cans et the recurring payment to be processed will be overnight / next day. This means that a user could get free access to paid content for up to 24 hours if their payment fails.

Even just doing an authorization check doesn't lock down the funds, so theoretically someone could be over their balance before the payment processes.

How do others handle this? What am I missing?

Comment: Typical subscription models offer a trial(Netflix). If payment isn't successful at the end of the trial the subscription ends. Its possible Netflix begins processing the payment a few hours before the trial actually ends.

Comment: @adam - I'm hoping there's a way around the free trial. We don't want to give a free trial to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a [webhook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks) with Stripe and you would be notified of when the payment has been processed. You could wait to give them access until you've been notified by Stripe.

Comment: we currently send a single payment, and when that comes back successful setup the recurring payment to start the following month. the workflow just feels messy. With Laravel and Cashier I would have thought there was a cleaner solution, hence revisiting our options

Comment: @TH1981, I've built a system before with Stripe where the customer enters their credit card info, etc and I then send to Stripe to get a `token` and I setup a Stripe `Customer` and create a `Subsription` for them. Stripe would then send a `webhook` call back whenever the subscription is paid. You could wait for that confirmation before granting access.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is your payment service provider or what pay methods you offer your customers?
But basically you got two options:

**1) Do not give your users access before the payment is in your account**
Not a good option i think and also not 100% safe.

**2) Handle the cancellations in a legal way**
I mean they buy a subscription at your shop. So your shop conditions (you hopefully got and show your customers) should cover all the payment parts. Maybe think about [Factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoring_(finance))

---

The thing is a customer is able to cancel a credit-card payment, a debit payment (sepa) and he is able to quit its recurring payment at the PayPal account and so on...

You can not rely on a success message from your payment provider in the checkout process. Most payment service providers got a server to server messaging system to update you with changes from transactions. For example PayPal has [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

You need a scheduled system with cronjobs that check cancellations at your payment provider APIs, send payment reminder emails when a recurring payment is needed (or automatically execute a recurring payment), extend the subscription service period when the notice period is done (year by year or a period based on a payment plan) ...and a lot of other stuff.

Basically payments are never 100% safe (not even dollar bills)!

Comment: As mentioned, we're using Laravel Cashier with Stripe. I'm not worried about cancellations - that happens and can be dealt with, just like cards that expire and aren't updated. There's a fear within the organization that the app will be taken advantage of leading to someone signing up, downloaded lots of the paywall content and cancelling before the payment processes. At least if they put in a chargeback, they have to do more effort?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @Thomas Baier